# How to do not allow certain characters duplicated using Regex

Tags: java, regex, nsregularexpression

only one letter can be written/selected as value, excepted for I, O, Q, S, X, Y, Z.

I've tried :

```
String regex="^(?!.*(.).*\1)([ABCDEFGHJKLMNPTURVW])+$|((?!OIXZYQS).)+$"
```

Comment: It would be best if you would provide example strings that succeed and fail.  Try to include a good variety of examples.

Answer (score 3):

Not so clear... To only allow upper alphabetic but disallow certain duplicated, e.g.

```
^(?!.*?([A-HJ-NPRT-W]).*\1)[A-Z]+$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Lj2Mzj/1)

The [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at `^` start checks if there is not another of `[A-HJ-NPRT-W]` by [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).
You could also do it [like this](https://regex101.com/r/Fo746I/1) which is slightly less efficient and maybe harder to maintain.

Comment: @WJS [Yes, it fails](https://tio.run/##NYxNC4JAFEX3/oqXtJgxHGgtIe2ihUYJQWowqdiYXzhPI8LfPk1ad3Pg3Mst@MDtIn0oJaq26RAKLZhomOUYScmlhCCTCG/DAIC2v5UiAYkcNYZGpFBxUZMTdqLOwxh4l0uqxzBl1l/ABurs@RPE9HzPN6nzn70kZhVremSt7rGcDlnFMblnkphX4i6Y5ZJwa@/2tnc4BvY5psyKojXV7hKvliad30ZjVOoD) maybe you did not escape the `\1`. Further I think with `matches()` in Java you don't need the start and end anchors but I'm not sure about that :)

Comment: You were right about the escape. It worked.  +1